Securely Storing Multiple Database Credentials in Node.js
I’m developing a monitoring application for my company, which operates in the automation field. This app will track the online/offline status of various equipment across multiple databases and servers, using data from equipment vendors' APIs as well as our own stored data.
Given the diversity of database types I need to manage, I chose a backend built with Node.js and Sequelize. However, I’m facing a challenge with securely storing the connection credentials for each database. Currently, I’m using a .env file for these credentials, but it’s getting unwieldy due to the large number of databases involved.
I’ve considered storing all credentials in a dedicated database that only my application can access, but I’m concerned about the security of this approach.
What do you recommend? Is it safer to store multiple database credentials within a single database, or should I stick with the .env file approach despite its size?

You could do that, but it's probably better to use something more robust like AWS secret manager or any of the other SaaS products. I know SO doesn't like software recommendations (or at least asking for them) but really you need a secret manager.
What's right for you will be more specific to your stack and architecture but most cloud providers have some version of this. A quick google search for "secret manager" will set you straight :)

I didn't know about the concept of secret manager. I'll look into it.
thank you for your recommendation ^^

No problem! No need to reinvent the wheel. Look into AWS / google Secret Manager or Bitwarden (provider agnostic). I would just go with whichever solution offered by the cloud host my company uses though. Good luck!
